# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : , when i access tickets.com json api

Tags: ajax, json, api, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from:

```
http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json
```

I'm using the jQuery `$.ajax` method and the code is written in my `index.html` file:

```
function getAPI() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json',
        type:"get",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
}
```

When I try it in the Chrome console, there is a message

```
Uncaught Syntax Error:Unexpected token:
```

I am very confused about what the problem is, can anyone help me?

Comment: The api returns `json` not `jsonp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content being returned is json, not jsonp as you specified in your dataType. Also, by setting jsonp to false, you're preventing a jsonp querystring from being appended to the URL by jquery, which is likely why the API you're using is returning json and not jsonp. I would try taking out the jsonp: false parameter.

Comment: function getAPI() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json',
        type:"get",
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
}

Comment: but the google chrome return value like this,"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: You're getting that error because it's a cross-domain request, which browsers prevent for security reasons. jsonp lets you get around it. I would try switching the dataType back to jsonp, and removing the jsonp: false attribute.